# Confluent control-center keeps quotes to the string key

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-control-center

I am producing events to a topic from Confluent control center.

The topic key is of String type and I am using `Serdes.String()` to deserialize it.

```scala
streamBuilder.stream[String, MyClass](inputTopic)(Consumed.`with`(Serdes.String(), MyClassSerde))
```

Because control center only allows json format, I must add quotes when publishing. So `"myKey"` instead of `myKey`.

But after deserialization the quotes are kept in the key.

Is this is a bug in confluent-cc ? How to send from confluent-cc without quotes ?

Comment: It might be. Have you tried contacting Confluent support since you need an enterprise license to use control center?